# post method in ASP.Net Form, but no data sent to sever

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I am using `AFNetworking` to sent a post request to a sever,
the request is successful, but no data were sent to the server.
the response string is the html form itself and 
the form is filled in the value i sent to the sever.

**Here is the code**

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com"];
 AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];

 NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            @"", @"__EVENTTARGET",
                            @"", @"__EVENTARGUMENT",
                            @"", @"__LASTFOCUS",
                            self.VIEWSTATE, @"__VIEWSTATE",
                            self.subject.text, @"ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$messagesubject",
                            self.message.text, @"ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$messagetext",
                            @"yes", @"ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btn_Submit",
                            nil];
[httpClient postPath:@"/post.aspx" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        NSString *responseStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:operation.responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSLog(@"Request Successful, response '%@'", responseStr);

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"[HTTPClient Error]: %@", error.localizedDescription);            

    }];
```

any idea?

Comment: Can you `NSLog` the params dictionary

Comment: Have a look at this answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17492327/restfull-architecture-http-get-put-requests/17492341#17492341

Comment: to ayush, I try it, but it's still the same

Comment: to icodebuster, here is the NSLog of params dictionary {
    "__EVENTARGUMENT" = "";
    "__EVENTTARGET" = "";
    "__LASTFOCUS" = "";
    "__VIEWSTATE" = "/wEPDwUJNDI4ODkwMzc4D2QWAmYPZBYEZ.......";
    "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$messagesubject" = "test_Subject";
    "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$messagetext" = "test_message";
    "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btn_Submit" = yes;
}

Comment: @JackKnight Then there is issue on server side can you put your server code also.

Comment: What format and headers are you sending and ar expected?

Comment: An example of @Wain's comment: some servers require the `Accept` header describe the type of content you want back; AFNetworking does not send this by default.  You might also want to look at the AFHTTPRequestOperationLogger extension so you can more easily see what you're sending and receiving.